# What is the canonical method for varying filter parameters based on the output of a preceding filter in Gstreamer?

Tags: c, gstreamer

I am looking at building an application using gstreamer but first have some questions regarding its capabilities with respect to a desired use case.

Say I wanted to build a pipeline that processes video data in a similar way as depicted below.

Videosrc -> Facedetect -> Crop -> Videosink

What is the canonical method for taking metadata produced on each frame by a given video filter (i.e. the bounding box from a facial detection filter) and passing it to succeeding filter to operate on (i.e. the Crop filter cropping each image on the bounding box provided by Facedetect).

I know there are properties and dynamic properties, but as far as I can tell from docs, those both require an idea of what you want to happen when you construct the pipeline.

I also know that you can attach metadata to the GstBuffer object which could potentially be used, but there would need to be an agreed upon interface in that case which doesn't seem very portable and may lack support across many elements with the same capabilities.